# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode' on Heroku logs

Tags: python, flask, heroku, redis

When running `heroku logs --tail` I get this error.

I'm implementing RedisToGo on my heroku app and I noticed that when I added `"REDISTOGO_URL"` to my code, it's returning this error. I don`t really know why when I add this it breaks my whole code. I was running it without the `"REDISTOGO_URL"` but realized I needed it on my app in order to work Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
redis_url = ('REDISTOGO_URL','redis://localhost:6379')
redis = redis.from_url(redis_url)

app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "redis"
app.config["SESSION_REDIS"] = redis

sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)
```

And this is the whole error code:

```
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662911+00:00 app[web.1]: connection_pool = ConnectionPool.from_url(url, db=db, **kwargs)
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662912+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 995, in from_url
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662912+00:00 app[web.1]: url = urlparse(url)
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662912+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 372, in urlparse
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662913+00:00 app[web.1]: url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662913+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 124, in _coerce_args
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662913+00:00 app[web.1]: return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662914+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 108, in _decode_args
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662914+00:00 app[web.1]: return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662914+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 108, in <genexpr>
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662915+00:00 app[web.1]: return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
2020-06-02T21:29:55.662916+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is appropriate only with a call to `os.getenv`, e.g.:

```
redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
#           ^^^^^^^^^
redis = redis.from_url(redis_url)
```

This is per: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo

The second value, `'redis://localhost:6379'`, is used when the environment does not have a variable called `REDISTOGO_URL`.

You can run `heroku config -a your_app_name_here` to see if `REDISTOGO_URL` is set.